# What is wrong with my Java import statement?

Tags: java

Hello I am new to Java and new to trying out Unit Testing for the first time on a simple program but my import.main.BalancedQuestionMarks; statement is not getting recognized in my test file. I don't understand why my test file isn't recognizing my main file.
Here is my test file

````
import main.BalancedQuestionMarks;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class BalancedQuestionMarksTest {

    @Test
    public void onlyQuestionMarkReturnsTrue() {
        assertTrue(BalancedQuestionMarksTest.hasBalancedMarks("??"), true);
    }
   
}```

Here is the error when I try to run:

java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method hasBalancedMarks(java.lang.String)
  location: class test.BalancedQuestionMarksTest
````

Comment: As the error says, the class `BalancedQuestionMarksTest` doesn't have a static method named `hasBalancedMarks` which takes a single `String` parameter. Did you mean to call `BalancedQuestionMarks.hasBalancedMarks("??")`?

Comment: I had originally had ```BalancedQuestionMarks.hasBalancedMarks("??")``` But then I get an error on line one saying "Can not resolve Symbol BalancedQuestionMarks " it is like line one is not importing correctly?

Comment: If you have exactly `import main.BalancedQuestionMarks;` then what you claim is _impossible_ (if the class does not exist, the import statement would have been an error instead): therefore, you must have typo'd something.

Comment: If the error was on line one, then I guess that is an error with the import statement?

Comment: Thanks all for the responses. I think I am going to have to nuke this project is and try again because I have no idea. My import main statement is just as it seems it should be...

Comment: Can you please share the hasBalancedMarks method?

Comment: ```public class BalancedQuestionMarks {public static boolean hasBalancedQuestionMarks(String str) {
        int marks = 0;
        for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
            if (ch == '?') {
                marks++;
            } else if (ch == '?') {
                marks--;
            }
        }
        return marks == 0;
    }
}```

Comment: The Answer: so after rebuilding my project and still having a problem. I figured it out. my test file was a file with in a file. So the File tree was like Main and Test and inside of Test was another file with the same name.   I deleted my test file and made a new one and remade my program and it works.  Thanks everyone!